# Docker-compose invalid. Additional properties are not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my *docker-compose.yml*:

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  control_node:
      hostname: controlnode
      container_name: controlnode
      build: ./control_node/
      command: tail -F anything
      privileged: true
      volumes:
      - ${CONTROL_NODE_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}:/shared
      networks:   
        labnet.io:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.0.2

  ubuntu-a:
      hostname: ubuntu-a   
      container_name: ubuntu-a
      build: ./ubuntu/
      command: tail -F anything
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_A_WEBSERVER_PORT}:80
      privileged: true
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_A_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared
      networks:   
        labnet.io:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.0.3

  ubuntu-b:
      hostname: ubuntu-b   
      container_name: ubuntu-b
      build: ./ubuntu/
      command: tail -F anything
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_B_APPSERVER_PORT}:8080
      privileged: true
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_B_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared
      networks:   
        labnet.io:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.0.4

  ubuntu-c:
      hostname: ubuntu-c   
      container_name: ubuntu-c
      build: ./ubuntu/
      command: tail -F anything
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_C_WEBSERVER_PORT}:80
      privileged: true
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_C_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared
      networks:   
        labnet.io:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.0.5

  ubuntu-d:
      hostname: ubuntu-d   
      container_name: ubuntu-d
      build: ./ubuntu/
      command: tail -F anything
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_D_APPSERVER_PORT}:8080
      privileged: true
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_D_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared
      networks:   
        labnet.io:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.0.6

networks:   
  labnet.io:
    name: labnet.io
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.10.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.10.0.1
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, I get:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> networks.labnet.io.ipam.config value Additional properties are not allowed ('gateway' was unexpected)
> networks.labnet.io value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)

Comment: From the docs on docker-compose v3: "Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment."

Comment: The easiest way to fix this would be to just delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the file.  Compose will [create a network named `default` and assign IP addresses for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  You similarly don't usually need to set `hostname:` or `container_name:`, and you can usually leave off `command:` to use the `CMD` from your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is resulted from the fact that you don't indent the "networks" property.

I used to get "(root) Additional property agent is not allowed", but indent solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the v3 syntax, the gateway field is not supported:

> Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ipam

However, setting static IPs on your containers is a strong code smell, it indicates your attempting to treat containers as small VMs, and that's the wrong design for working with containers. Same goes for setting a container name. Doing this breaks the ability to update the container without some kind of outage because you have to stop the old container and delete it to free the IP and name. Unless you need privileged, I'd also remove that. If you don't need write access to the ssh keys, only mount those read only. I'd move the command to be part of your image definition. And you should define your image name with your hub username (or local registry). The result looks like:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  control_node:
      image: username/control:latest
      build: ./control_node/
      volumes:
      - ${CONTROL_NODE_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh:ro
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}:/shared

  ubuntu-a:
      image: username/ubuntu:latest
      build: ./ubuntu/
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_A_WEBSERVER_PORT}:80
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_A_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh:ro
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared

  ubuntu-b:
      image: username/ubuntu:latest
      build: ./ubuntu/
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_B_APPSERVER_PORT}:8080
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_B_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh:ro
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared

  ubuntu-c:
      image: username/ubuntu:latest
      build: ./ubuntu/
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_C_WEBSERVER_PORT}:80
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_C_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh:ro
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared

  ubuntu-d:
      image: username/ubuntu:latest
      build: ./ubuntu/
      ports:
      - ${UBUNTU_D_APPSERVER_PORT}:8080
      volumes:
      - ${UBUNTU_D_SSH}:/home/ansible/.ssh:ro
      - ${SHARED_FOLDER}/shared:/shared
```

Lastly, I'll add that many of the things you are trying to do don't seem appropriate for Swarm Mode which  is the reason for the version 3 syntax. If you don't need to support Swarm Mode, then one of the [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) formats would likely be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: When I run your version, I get:

ERROR: Named volume "${HOME}/ansible-lab/ssh/control_node:/home/ansible/.ssh:ro" is used in service "control_node" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

Comment: @user17007397 where did `${HOME}` come from?

Comment: downvote for preaching about how docker should be used re addressing in one limited use case that does not universally apply to all docker use cases.

Comment: @keen The "limited use case" described here is swarm mode, which is the reason to use the v3 spec. Features like setting the container name, network parameters, building images, etc, are not supported in swarm and therefore aren't supported in v3. If you aren't using swarm, then don't use v3, and you won't be limited to this use case.

Comment: @BMitch which is a perfectly valid answer that is not event remotely obvious about v2 vs v3.  and it that doesn't preach about `setting static IPs on your containers is a strong code smell` that may or may not apply to other use cases.    there are other reasons to use v3, of course, that aren't relevant to the convo - needing to set `external: true` for a network for example.

Comment: @keen there is no reason to use v3 other than swarm mode. External networks are available in v2, and v2 continued to be developed after the v3 release. To use the latest compose file version, that's compose-spec, which removed the version number, but you need to be sure your tooling parsing the file is using compose-spec since it will otherwise fall back as v1.

Comment: Static IPs on a container are a strong code smell because you cannot replace the container before the previous container has completely stopped, the compose file isn't portable to other environments, and it implies you are not using DNS and are trying to communicate directly to the container rather than publishing ports on the host.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Releases 1.27.0+ have merged v2/v3 file formats, as you can see in https://github.com/docker/compose/releases
So, the version property is now only informative.

However, as mention by BMitch, if support to swarm mode is needed, the field gateway can't be in compose-file because is not supported in version 3 syntax.

---

I had the same problem here with docker-compose version 1.25.5, but no longer in 1.29.2.

```
version: '3'
networks:
        nginx_net:
                driver: bridge
                ipam:
                        driver: default
                        config:
                                - gateway: "192.168.0.254"
                                  subnet: "192.168.0.0/24"

...

docker network inspect compose_nginx_net
[
    {
        "Name": "compose_nginx_net",
        "Id": "2137c736e0c56d90cbc657a6a9f819a117edb273fdde1a4963ee68769901d368",
        "Created": "2021-12-12T14:42:15.33387384Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.254"
                }
            ]
        },
...
```

Comment: It's still an invalid compose file according to the version 3 spec. What's different is newer versions of compose completely ignore the version, but if you run this with an older version of compose or deploy with swarm mode (the reason behind v3) you'll have errors.

Comment: Thanks, BMitch.
Just started in this docker world.
It seems to me a good thing, though, knowing that releases 1.27.0+ have merged v2/v3 file formats.
The version property is now only informative, right?

Comment: Depends on whether you only want to support compose files running on your own machine, or if you need to support them running on other machines where you don't control the compose version, and especially if you want to support swarm mode. If you don't need to support swarm mode, there's no reason for version 3.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Already edited the answer to be more accurate.